# v-model in dynamic component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a list of dynamic components that I render with a for loop.

```
<component
        v-for="component in components"
        :key="component.componentId"
        :is="component.type"
        :componentId="component.componentId">
</component>
```

One of the different component types is an element that contains an input field. I want to attach `v-model` to that input.

```
<input type="text" :name="name">
```

works but when I do

```
<input type="text" :name="name" v-model="value">
```

I get no errors but the component is not rendered. However

```
<input type="text" :name="name" :value="value" @input="setValue">
```

works, if used with an appropriate method `setValue` to update the value attribute.

How should I use v-model in the component?

Comment: Possible to create a fiddle of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently dynamic type bindings don't work with `v-model`. Found [a commit](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/commit/f35f7e35cd48efc21e759752058c07a1ff32cfb6) in the repository that confirms this. For some reason it doesn't give me the warning, even though `process.env.NODE_ENV == undefined`.

In the original question I stripped a lot of code to make it more readable but seems like I missed the important part.